# jquery/javascript - overwriting values that exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have something similar to this:

```
...
meta: {
  'orderby' : 'firstname',
  'page' : 1,
  'per' : 10
}
...
```

When I get send the request using ajax, part of my response contains some of this meta data. So I overwrite it with the new stuff. The server might send back something like:

```
meta: {
  'page' : 1,
  'per' : 10
}
```

The problem is that it overwrites the `orderby` key to be `undefined`. I don't want to have the server send back everything, how can I leave a key's value if the key isn't sent back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you've said you're using jQuery, you can use its [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function:

```
jQuery.extend(originalMeta, returnedMeta);
```

That will only overwrite properties in the target (`originalMeta`, in the above) with properties from the source (`returnedMeta` in the above) that actually exist. (No need to assign the result of the function to `originalMeta`, it's modified in place.)

It's also dead easy without relying on jQuery:

```
var name;
for (name in returnedMeta) {
    if (returnedMeta.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        originalMeta[name] = returnedMeta[name];
    }
}
```

That uses a `for..in` loop to loop through all (enumerable) properites on `returnedMeta`, filters out any it inherits from its prototype (it probably doesn't inherit any, but...), and for ones that exist copies the values into `originalMeta`.

Comment: Does `extend()` really add properties in place? All this time... :P Again, the vote cap...

Comment: @alex: LOL, yup. It *also* returns the result, but it does it in place. From the docs: *"Keep in mind that the `target` object (first argument) will be modified, and will also be returned from `$.extend()`."*

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

```
var meta = $.extend(meta, {
    'page': 1,
    'per': 10
});
```

[T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848960/jquery-javascript-overwriting-values-that-exist/5848971#5848971) that the first argument's object is modified, no need to return (though it will work as well).

> The problem is that it overwrites the orderby key to be undefined

It doesn't overwrite the property, it overwrites the entire `Object`. When you access an `Object`'s property that doesn't exist, you get `undefined`.